# "remount: not found" error

Tags: adb, partitions, mount

I want to install an application as a system application.

To do so, I must remount the system partition RW, to do so I run the command `adb shell remount rw` in a terminal, but I get the error `/system/bin/sh: remount: not found`.

How can I remount the system partition RW?

Answer (score 9):

The command is: `adb remount`, please try this first. However, if it doesn't work, make sure your device is rooted, and try these commands:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Those commands will directly remount the system as RW. However, you must be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the exact same issue: "remount: not found". Seems there are different syntax possibilities depending on the OS or updated libs. In case the syntax doesn't suit, it just interprets 'remount' as a command "not found".

Then I tried

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

and it worked.

The strange thing is, a few months before, just after having rooted my device, this worked: `mount -o rw;remount /system`.
There seems to be also: `mount -o remount,rw /system`.

Just try different syntaxes. If you rooted your device, one must work.